# Setting value to a computed value

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

I am trying to set an input value in vue-formulate which is a computed value. The value gets computed (check console) but it is not set as input value.

Reproduction code - https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-reproduction-template-forked-j9jtc?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: your computed property always returning null. So it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `v-model` the computed property with the `FormulateInput` instead of one way binding the `value`. Here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-reproduction-template-forked-b8ijc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
<FormulateInput
                name="lmp_mcp_difference"
                type="number"
                v-model="days_difference"
                label="Difference of days between LMP and Registration Date"
              />
```

For updating the `values` property you need to assign the `values` as it has lost reactivity from the vue instance.Updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-reproduction-template-forked-b8ijc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: It is null only initially. When dates are selected the value gets computed. You can see the console output here - https://tppr.me/cpFl4

Comment: v-model doesn't work because then the original `values` object doesn't get updated more than once https://tppr.me/tk3Eo Please use the full reproduction app I have shared to test your answer.

Comment: Used separate `v-model` and a watch on it instead of mutating `values` in the function - https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-reproduction-template-forked-0uw2f?file=/src/App.vue I like this approach better